# Why do some logic gate chips have a reversed pin layout?

Tags: logic-gates, pins, 7400

I am using some logic chips by Texas Instruments, namely SN74HC02N, SN74HC04N, SN74HC32N and others.

When I connected them in my circuit, the SN74HC02N NOR-gate didn't work as expected, so I searched for a datasheet. It showed that the pin layout for the chip was reversed: It was Y, A, B instead of A, B, Y.

The other chips from the same family and manufacturer that I have are all A, B, Y. 
This is very counter-intuitive and doesn't make much sense.

Why does this one chip have a different pin layout?

Is there an alternative version that has a A, B, Y layout?

Comment: For  sure NOR was backwards to OR et al,....;)   it was not designed by the famous Polish IC designer who also did HP's calculator. ;) j/k .. even the CD4001 was different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOR gate needs extra transistors, compared to NAND. In the days of single-layer metal, routing with that single layer may have required moving the "Y" output, so as to have the most compact IC layout and acceptable cost for the extra transistors.

Comment: they could have rotated it.